# A chemical rebus

Tags: rebus

[image: chemicalRebus]

Its not related to chemistry though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By "not related to chemistry", I assume you mean the answer is not a word related to chemistry, not that this puzzle has nothing to do with chemistry...

The group of 4 discs on the left looks like

> Helium - a helium-4 nucleus, specifically.  Also known as an alpha particle.

The red disc looks like

> An electron, not a proton like I originally thought.  Also known as a beta particle.

The formula to the left refers to

> The Arrhenius Equation, which relates a rate constant (k) to a constant factor (A), gas constant (R), Temperature (T), and activation energy (Ea): k = A * e^(-Ea/RT)
>  k/[e^(-Ea/RT)] is just A.

So you get:

> Alpha + beta - A = Alphabet.

Comment: Not a proton.... I didn't know what color they were so...

Comment: Ah, I see now.  I'll edit.

Comment: wow, luckly is not chemist related lol